# main class not found in spark scala program

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

//package com.jsonReader

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
//import org.apache.spark.implicits._


//import sqlContext.implicits._
object json {

    def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): JsObject = js.as[JsObject].fields.foldLeft(Json.obj()) {
    case (acc, (k, v: JsObject)) => {
        val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
                acc.deepMerge(flatten(v, nk))
    }
    case (acc, (k, v: JsArray)) => {
        val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
                val arr = flattenArray(v, nk).foldLeft(Json.obj())(_++_)
                acc.deepMerge(arr)
    }
    case (acc, (k, v)) => {
        val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
                acc + (nk -> v)
    }
    }

    def flattenArray(a: JsArray, k: String = ""): Seq[JsObject] = {
            flattenSeq(a.value.zipWithIndex.map {
            case (o: JsObject, i: Int) =>
            flatten(o, s"$k[$i]")
            case (o: JsArray, i: Int) =>
            flattenArray(o, s"$k[$i]")
            case a =>
            Json.obj(s"$k[${a._2}]" -> a._1)
            })
    }

    def flattenSeq(s: Seq[Any], b: Seq[JsObject] = Seq()): Seq[JsObject] = {
            s.foldLeft[Seq[JsObject]](b){
            case (acc, v: JsObject) =>
            acc:+v
            case (acc, v: Seq[Any]) =>
            flattenSeq(v, acc)
            }
    }
def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val appName = "Stream example 1"
            val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[*]")
            //val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
            //val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
        val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc);
    //val spark=sqlContext.sparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("json Reader")
            val df = sqlContext.read.json("C://Users//ashda//Desktop//test.json")
            val set = df.select($"user",$"status",$"reason",explode($"dates")).show()
            val read = flatten(df)
            read.printSchema()
          df.show()         

    }

}
```

I'm trying to use this code to flatten a higly nested json. For this I created a project and converted it to a maven project. I edited the pom.xml and included the libraries I needed but when I run program it says "Error: Could not find or load main class".

I tried converting the code to sbt project and then run but I get the same error. I tried packaging the code and run through spark-submit which gives me same error. Please let me know what am I missing here. I have tried I could for this.

Thanks

Comment: What do your `pom.xml`/`build.sbt` look like?

Comment: [link]( https://pastebin.com/mnC7D4MK) - pom.xml

Comment: name := "jsonExtract"
version:= "1.0"
organization :="enquero"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.1",
                            "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.5.2",
       "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11"  % "2.2.1",
       "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.1")

Comment: Please post your project structure.

Comment: @franklin please refer [link](https://imgur.com/a/7j0IK9Z)

Comment: How are you executing the project? Usually failure to find/load the main class is because you're not executing the program from the right directory; sbt has a particular way of looking through the project structure. You may need to change the `root` setting in your sbt file.

Comment: @franklin I'm executing the project via spark-submit. As my environment variable are set , I think i can use this command from any directory. However I ran the command from my root directory and still got same error. Could you please tell me the `root` sbt setting to change?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question with these details instead of posting them as comments. Also, most of the code that is in your question is irrelevant here and can be taken out. Please produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say, but maybe you have many classes that qualify as main so the build tool does not know which one to choose. Maybe try to clean the project first `sbt clean`.

Anyway in scala the preferred way to define a main class is to extend the App -trait.

```
object SomeApp extends App
```

Then the whole object body will become your main method.
You can also define in your build.sbt the main class. This is necessary if you have many objects that extend the App -trait.

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("io.example.SomeApp")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question for sbt configurations. I also got the same issues which I resolved recently and made some basic mistakes which I would like you to note :

**1. Configure your sbt file**

go to build.sbt file and see that the scala version you are using is compatible with spark.As per version 2.4.0 of spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ ,scala version required is 2.11.x and not 2.12.x . So, even though your IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ) shows the latest version of scala or the version you downloaded, change it to compatible version. Also, include this line of code

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.6"
```

2.11.x is your scala version

**2. File Hierarchy** 
Make sure your Scala file is under /src/main/scala package only

**3. Terminal** 
If your IDE allows you to launch terminal within it, launch it(IntelliJ allows, Not sure of Eclipse or any other) OR Go to terminal and change directory to your project directory

then run :

```
sbt clean
```

This will clear any libraries loaded previously or folders created after compilation.

```
sbt package
```

This will pack your files into a single jar file under target/scala-/ package

Then submit to spark :

```
spark-submit target/scala-<version>/<.jar file> --class "<ClassName>(In your case , com.jsonReader.json)" --jars target/scala-<version>/<.jar file> --master local[*]
```

Note here that -- if specified in a program isnt required here